# NETSTAT -a -b not working in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

In cmd.exe I enter:

```
NETSTAT -a -b
```

=> result not working and show `The requested operation requires elevation`

How to check port software running in windows 7

Comment: Not programming-related - [see the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - off-topic

Answer (score 16):

You should have administrator rights to do this action

Run cmd.exe from administrator

Answer (score 3):

found following answer from [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/error-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation/cdd97f8c-7f58-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?msgId=353fac75-9458-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) :

> Open the command prompt by right clicking on the command prompt icon
>   and select "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8/8.1 click on Start button, type 'cmd', right click on Command Prompt and choose Run as administrator.